Is there a way to retrieve your most played albums (or songs) for a particular duration through MusicKit?
I am trying to retrieve my most played albums (or songs) for Apple Music through MusicKit, either by API or the Swift library.
I have tried using MusicLibraryRequest from the documentation but it doesnt have a duration option, it just sorts of dumps the data.
func fetchMostPlayedSongs(limit: Int) async throws {
   var request = MusicLibraryRequest<Song>()
   request.limit = limit
   request.sort(by: \.playCount, ascending: false
   let response = try await request.response()
}

Is there any other way to do this or a hack around it?

By duration, do you mean a particular period in time (like "2021-2023")?

@AbhinavMathur yeah. Or 01-01-2024 to 24-04-2024
